# Lodash orderBy delete key index in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

When I use the orderBy function of Lodash () it returns the array with the correct order, but changes the indexes by simple keys 0,1,2,3...
I searched a little bit everywhere, but I couldn't find a solution to keep my keys.

Example :

`Data :`

```
var a = {
    "65191320": {
        "date":"20180220", 
        "comment":"Hello world"
    },
    "849165164": {
            "date":"20180221", 
            "comment":"Hello world"
        }
}
```

`main.js :`

```
var b = _.orderBy(a, ['date'], ['desc']);
console.log(b);
```

`Output :`

```
{
    0: {
        "date":"20180221", 
        "comment":"Hello world"
    },
    1: {
        "date":"20180220", 
        "comment":"Hello world"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the keys have been changed. Is that common ? How can I keep the keys to the index finger ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are ordering an object and not an array in the first place?

Comment: because the return of the function to get the data is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no way to reorder plain object properties.

Property order is not guaranteed in JavaScript objects. Only an array or a Map can guarantee that. Therefore, ordering plain object makes no sense in the first place.

Here's [another answer that expands on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

The `orderBy()` function is meant for arrays and arrays only. Underneath, it uses `baseSortBy()`, which looks like this:

```
function baseSortBy(array, comparer) {
  var length = array.length;

  array.sort(comparer);
  while (length--) {
    array[length] = array[length].value;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Note the `while` loop body: it sets `array[length]`. If `array` is an object, it will set properties to be numbers.

Comment: Okay, I understand why the indexes are being transformed ! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by doing this.

```
_.fromPairs(_.orderBy(_.toPairs(a), ['date'], ['desc']))
```

The result should be like what you expected.

Cheers.